# maven build fails in jenkins for child module error

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a maven build with the below structure.

TEST/pom.xml -in root directory
TEST/A/B/pom.xml- child module

maven clean install works fine from command prompt. But, it fails when I run from jenkins with this error.

**[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST/A/B of  /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST/pom.xml does not exist @**

Please help here as I have failed to resolve this till now.

Comment: it would be really useful to be able to see the `pom.xml` files for both projects (parent/child). Could you perhaps add them to some github gist?

Comment: should i paste it here?

Comment: something like https://gist.github.com/ would be preferable. pasting it there helps keep this question readable (without having to scroll a lot ;) ) - and at the same time anyone who wants to view the file is only one click away from a nice page that shows your file (usually, with the proper syntax highlighting as well, which also helps!)

Comment: I am not sure if i can paste the code here.